# How to generate random numbers from convex combination of densities?

Tags: statistics, numerical-methods, matlab, sampling, density-function

I'm solving a numerical problem in Matlab and I need to generate a sample from a non-standard probability density function. I'm fully aware of that old trick of inverting the cumulative distribution function and applying it on random numbers from an Uniform $[0,1]$ distribution but I think this won't do the trick here, since there's no closed form for the desired cdf.

Let $J$ be a fixed integer (odd). Define $\theta_{j} = j - (J+1)/2$, for all $j = 1, 2, ..., J$. Let $f(x, \theta)$ be the probability density function of a Normal $(\theta, 1)$ distribution. Now we define the following density:

> $g(x) = \frac{\sum_{j=1}^{J}f(x,\theta_{j})}{J}$

It's easy to see that $g( ) $ has all of the good properties of pdf. My question is how to generate a sample coming from this density. I'm working on Matlab but I think the same procedure would work everywhere. Any ideas or hints?

Answer (score 2):

Pick $j$ uniformly, and then pick $x$ from the $N(\theta_j,1)$ distribution.

ADDED:  this works because the density function of the output of this process matches your $g$ formula.  For any set $A$, we have $P(x \in A)$ is given by $\sum_{i=1}^J \int_A f(y,\theta_j) \,dy$, by conditioning on the randomly chosen $j$. But this is exactly what your $\int_A g(y)\,dy$ gives.

Comment: Ok, but could you give a justification why this should work? Thanks!